# Array initialization with self-invoking function

Tags: javascript, iife, self-invoking-function

I'm trying to initialize an array with self-invoking function, assume for simplicity as an example, that initial values are squares of numbers from 0 to 4. The `new` keyword creates new object, so one can access fields of newly created object with `this.x` or `this[x]` inside the IIFE body, following the `new` keyword. The code is:

```
var arr = new (function() {
    for (var i=0; i<5; i++) { this[i]=i*i; }
})();
```

Now, you can access corresponding fields of variable `arr` like `arr[4]`, and get `16`. That's perfectly fine if you only work with `arr` like with an object, but once you try to treat it like an array, you have a problem. Namely, you can't apply functions like `reduce` to it:

```
< arr.reduce(...);
> TypeError: arr.reduce is not a function
```

That's because `arr` is really an object, not an array:

```
< arr;
> ({0:0, 1:1, 2:4, 3:9, 4:16})
```

So here is my question: how to avoid such behavior within this method? How to make JavaScript interpret this newly created object as an array?

Comment: Why not just return an array? For example, `var arr = (function() { ret = []; for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) { ret[i] = i * i; } return ret; )();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without the IEFE it is shorter and more clear:

```
var arr = [];
for (var i=0; i<5; i++) arr[i] = i*i;
```

Without the additional counter variable `i`, you could do:

```
for (var arr=[]; arr.length<5; ) arr[arr.length] = Math.pow(arr.length, 2);
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to use the `new` keyword for that...

```
var arr = (function() {
               var x = [];
               for (var i=0; i<4; i++)
                   x.push(i*i);
               return x;
           })();
```

the `new` keyword creates an object and sets its constructor, then binds `this` to it and calls the function. You don't need anything of that except calling the function, so just do so.

Comment: The purpose was to write a oneliner and avoid construction like `var x=[]; ... return x;`.
Compare to:
`var arr=[]; for (var i=0;i<5;i++) arr.push(i*i);`
OK, this one is a oneliner, but initial values may be calculated in a more complicated way.

Comment: @AndreiSmolensky: the point of using anonymous functions and immediately calling them is because of scoping rules of Javascript (the fact that you cannot have block-level locals). Writing the initialization code at toplevel will leak variables (e.g. `i` in your example). Any amount of javascript code can be a one liner because except for some idiotic rules about semicolon insertion a newline is equivalent to a space for Javascript.